# replacing and adding 3 different params to the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds an param to the url when I click the assigned button - next click replaces it with a new param - this work great.

However - now I have three buttons - and I want each button to assign a param to the url - and replacing any params added by any of the other buttons. It also needs to be placed last behind the params that are already there.

so:

```
 (button1)  click3:  /m4n?ecom-query=imac&seid=etailer-products&viewMode=3?param=grid
 (button2)  click4:  /m4n?ecom-query=imac&seid=etailer-products&viewMode=3?param=list
 (button3)  click5:  /m4n?ecom-query=imac&seid=etailer-products&viewMode=3?param=smalllist
```

The url before ?param is dynamic and can look different.

```
$('.click2').on('click', function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('?param=list') > -1) {
        url = url.replace("?param=list", "") + '?param=grid'
    } else {
        url = url.replace("?param=grid", "") + '?param=list'
    }
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

How do I do this, I tried to modify my existing script but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a small error in your approach:
All parameters in url should be connected with an &
so now your url should look like that

```
 /m4n?ecom-query=imac&seid=etailer-products&viewMode=3&param=grid
```

now if you want to replace old pram, you need to remove the old value also. For that you can use regex as in following code

```
url = url.replace(/\&param=.*/,'') + '&param=list'
```

So the full code would be:

```
$('.click2').on('click', function() {
    console.log("click2 Clicked");
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.replace(/\&param=.*/,'') + '&param=list';
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah that works perfect. Thanks for the explanation aswell - this looked so simple!